# Div constant aspect ratio and responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a scrollable container div with the aspect ratio 16:9. Inside the div there is a lot of smaller divs. The smaller divs should be visible by 7 divs in width and 5 in height. Like this:

https://app.box.com/s/pbg3obc3k4lq6e4i2wdny32r1qlz5yv9

I want to keep the aspect ratio and number of inner divs visible constant, even though the windows is resized etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maintain aspect ratio when resizing a DIV using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div-using-css)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the width and height of the divs to specific percentage. In you case width= 100/7~=14% and height = 100/5=20%.

```
.day{
    display:inline-block;
    width:14%;
    height:20%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sygn/5skw6y2z/1)